# SugarCRM - Custom Print Layout

Tags: sugarcrm

I created a model in SugarCRM and I need to print the details view. But this must be printed with a different layout.

It must have the company logo for example, if I just wanted do print the bean information, the default print would be sufficient, but I need something closer to a report, because this info will be given to the costumer.

I would like to know if there is a way to create a printing template, and if there is, how can I create one?

Thanks for your help, if you need more information please comment.

rfnpinto

Answer (score 0):

Even in SugarCRM CE you can leverage the included Sugarpdf class, which is an extension of TCPDF.

If you have SugarCRM Professional you can find examples of this in the Quotes module. If not, you're flying blind, so I can give you the gist of it.

Using the Contacts module as an example, create `/custom/modules/Contacts/views/view.sugarpdf.php` with contents like the following:

```
<?php
require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.sugarpdf.php');
/**
 * this defines the view that will drive which PDF Template we use
 */
class CustomContactsViewSugarpdf extends ViewSugarpdf{
  public function display(){
    $this->sugarpdfBean->process();
    $this->sugarpdfBean->Output($this->sugarpdfBean->fileName,'D');
    sugar_die('');
  }
}
```

Create `/custom/modules/Contacts/sugarpdf/sugarpdf.pdfout.php` with contents like the following:

```
    $contact = BeanFactory::getBean($_REQUEST['record_id']);
    if(empty($contact->id)){
      sugar_die('Could not load contact record');
    }

    $name_str = "<p><strong>Name: {$contact->name}</strong></p>";

    $this->writeHTML($name_str);
    $this->drawLine();
  }
  function buildFileName(){
    $this->fileName = 'ContactPDFOut.pdf';
  }
}
```

From there, you can print a PDF document per your format if you hit the URI `index.php?module=Contacts&action=sugarpdf&sugarpdf=pdfout&record_id=1234`

Once that's working in the way you want, you can add a button the Contacts Detailview to access that URI more easily. Dig into `/custom/modules/Contacts/metadata/detailviewdefs.php` and find the existing buttons array. It'll look something like this:

`'buttons'=>array('EDIT', 'DUPLICATE', 'DELETE', 'FIND_DUPLICATES'`

Just enhance this with your own button and hidden input

```
'buttons'=>array('EDIT', 'DUPLICATE', 'DELETE', 'FIND_DUPLICATES',array(
  'sugar_html'=>array(
    'type' => 'submit',
    'value' => '(Wrongfully Hardcoded Label) Print PDf',
    'htmlOptions'=>array(onclick => 'this.form.action.value=\'sugarpdf\';this.form.sugarpdf.value=\'pdfout\'')
  )
)
```

...
The hidden array should be part of `$viewdefs['Meetings']['DetailView']['templateMeta']['form']` and defined like so:
`'hidden' => array('<input type="hidden" name="sugarpdf">'),`

I haven't tested this recently but this is the general idea of adding custom Print PDF abilities to any particular screen within SugarCRM. TCPDF options are pretty extensive and forming the template *just right* is going to be very tedious, but I think once the "plumbing" is working here you'll figure that bit out, but feel free to ask followup questions.